# Call C method in C# by DllImport - attempt to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, c++, c, dllimport

I have a dll - Lib.dll(written in С or C++). I need to call a function:

```
extern “C” DWORD call_sb_kernel(
DWORD       func,
void        *in_arg,
void        *out_arg);
```

This description of the parameters:
    DWORD       func - is a anumber
    void        *in_arg - pointer to

```
typedef struct tagInArg{
void        *Reserved;
void        *in_struct;     
} InArg;
```

void        *out_arg pointer to

```
typedef struct tagOutArg{
DWORD           ErrorCode;        
DWORD           Flags;            
void            *Reserved;
void            *out_struct;     
} OutArg;
```

return result from function.

I call this function at C#

```
    [DllImport(LibPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private static extern long call_sb_kernel(uint func, [In, Out] InArg inArg, [In, Out]       OutArg outArg);


    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 128)]
    public struct InArg
    {
        public IntPtr Reserved;
        public IntPtr in_struct;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 128)]
    public struct OutArg
    {
        public Int32 ErrorCode;
        public Int32 Flags;
        public IntPtr Reserved;
        public IntPtr out_struct;
    }

    public void Test()
    {
        var outArg = new OutArg();
        var res = call_sb_kernel_std(0, new InArg(), outArg);
    }
```

I've tried a lot of options. This is the last version.But I get a runtime error -  "Attempt to read or write protected memory". How do I call this function?

Comment: This is one of the options I've tried(Size = 128).

Comment: I have a description of this function. but I do not know how to properly call.

Comment: Setting the `Size` property is unnecessary, the automatic size of fields matches the size the C code would expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`call_sb_kernel` expects two pointers, not structures. Change your definition to `ref InArg inArg, out OutArg outArg` and use it like `call_sb_kernel_std(0, ref inArg, out outArg);`.

Comment: call_sb_kernel_std(0, ref inArg, out outArg) - It is work.Thank you.